# Не получается нажать на кнопку *Войти через* python selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь нажать на эту кнопку

[image: Login as Facebook]

Пытался делать так:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signup_with_facebook"]/button').click()
```

Выдало:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Попробовал:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signup_with_facebook"]/button')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(
    button
).click(
    button
).perform()
```

Выдало:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLButtonElement] has no size and location
```

И дело не в полном прогружении сайта:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.myheritage.com/deep-nostalgia')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="masterPageHeader"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/span').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signup_with_facebook"]/button'))).click()
```

Ошибка:

```
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Как это сделать?

Буду благодарен любой идеей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://www.myheritage.com/deep-nostalgia")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1440, 1024)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="masterPageHeader"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/span').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/button"))).click()
```

Так вроде работает.
Использовал все то, что было у Вас, только добавил импорт и обращался непосредственно к button.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]